# mySQL two COUNTS in one query with 3 tables involved

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables namely: Town; Village; Farmers...and I need to COUNT how many Farmers there are per Village, and how many Villages there are per Town. I'm new to php and mysql, so my code is still rubbish.. So far I have done the code for the query:

```
$query = "SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT village.villageID) AS cnt_village, 
COUNT( farmer.farmerID ) AS cnt_farmers
FROM town LEFT JOIN village ON village.townID = town.townID
LEFT JOIN farmer ON farmer.villageID = village.villageID
GROUP BY town.townID
ORDER BY town.townName";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

It already outputs the correct counts like this:

```
----TOWN--------VILLAGES----FARMERS-----
| Caibiran   |      2     |    23       |
| Culaba     |      7     |    39       |
|      TOTAL |      9     |    62       |
```

It works well until I try to do a search for a specific town. What happens is that the values of the Farmers column displays the correct value for the specified town. But the whole table is still displayed with the farmers column of the other towns showing 0.

It shows this:

```
 ----TOWN--------VILLAGES----FARMERS-----
| Caibiran   |      2     |    23       |
| Culaba     |      7     |    0        |
|      TOTAL |      9     |    23       |
```

But what I really want is this:

```
----TOWN--------VILLAGES----FARMERS-----
| Caibiran   |      2     |    23       |
|      TOTAL |      2     |    23       |
```

But I don't know how to do it. And I've ran out of ideas. Please help me.

Comment: I can't say without testing but try removing the `LEFT JOIN`s and try a plain equijoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve the problem?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT village.villageID) AS cnt_village, 
COUNT( farmer.farmerID ) AS cnt_farmers
FROM town
JOIN village ON village.townID = town.townID
JOIN farmer ON farmer.villageID = village.villageID
GROUP BY town.townID
ORDER BY town.townName
```

As there won't be any farmer to join with, the rows should be removed from the result set.